# NodeJS docker image to run Angular test in gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab-ci, docker-image, angular-test

I have a small Angular app which I am try to build using gitlab-ci and node docker image, when I try to run the test using the command ***npm run test*** it fails with the following error :

`ERROR [launcher]: No binary for Chrome browser on your platform. Please, set "CHROME_BIN" env variable.`

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
- build

variables:
  NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY: https://test.com/xx/api/npm/npm-all

build:
  stage: build
  image: node:12.9
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build:prod
    - npm run test
  tags:
    - DOCKER
```

In the above code **npm run test** executes **ng test** as configured in the package.json

I was able to run the build but when I run the test it looks for a chrome browser, I also tried running the test in a headless way using the below command but resulted in the same error :

`ng test --no-watch --browsers=ChromeHeadless`

How do I add the chrome feature to this build ?

Answer (score 1):

Either install Chrome by yourself or try an existing [Docker image that already includes it](https://hub.docker.com/r/timbru31/node-chrome).